# Dynamic table creation using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using something like this to create dynamic table

```
    for(var i=0;i<nrRows;i++){
        row=document.createElement('tr');
        for(var j=0;j<nrCols;j++){
        cell=document.createElement('td');
        cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i+' '+j))
        row.appendChild(cell);
        }
        tbo.appendChild(row);
    }
```

Now I want the first row to be filled with column headers. And I want to give ID to each textbox in each row. How do I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(i == 0)
{
    cell = document.createElement('th');
    //give column header names
}
else
{
    cell = document.createElement('td');
    var inputFld = document.createElement('input');
    inputFld.type = "text"; //input type = textfield
    inputFld.id = "input" + i;//assign id to input field
    cell.appendChild(inputFld);
}
```

Comment: You might want to concatenate `"_"+j` (or something) on the end of your input ids so that every input in the row doesn't have the same id...

Comment: yes, that's why I've concatenated i to the id, even j can also be concatenated to generate unique id across the table

Comment: @SunilKumarBM - the id attribute is supposed to be unique across the entire document...

Answer (score 3):

*"Now I want the first row to be filled with column headers."*

```
cell = document.createElement(i===0 ? 'th' : 'td');
```

*"And I want to give ID to each textbox in each row."*

What textboxes? You're not currently creating textboxes. Each `id` attribute should be unique, so assuming you had actually created some textboxes you could just set the `id` to `i + "_" + j` (similar to what you've already got for your `.createTextNode()`) so that other parts of your code could easily calculate the `id` that would be required to access any particular cell.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(i == 0)
{
    cell = document.createElement('th');
}
else
{

    cell = document.createElement('td');
    var inputFld = document.createElement('input');
    inputFld.type = "text"; //input type = textfield
    var count=table.rows.length;
    inputFld.id = "NewTb" + count;
    cell.appendChild(inputFld);
}
```